# Performance of Arrays and Hashes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, performance, hash

I have a program that will store many instances of one class, let's say up to 10.000 or more. The class instances have several properties that I need from time to time, but their most important one is the ID.

```
class Document
  attr_accessor :id
  def ==(document)
    document.id == self.id
  end
end
```

Now, what is the fastest way of storing thousands of these objects?

I used to put them all into an array of Documents:

```
documents = Array.new
documents << Document.new
# etc
```

Now an alternative would be to store them in a Hash:

```
documents = Hash.new
doc = Document.new
documents[doc.id] = doc
# etc
```

In my application, I mostly need to find out whether a document exists at all. Is the Hash's `has_key?` function significantly faster than a linear search of the Array and the comparison of `Document` objects? Are both within *O(n)* or is `has_key?` even *O(1)*. Will I see the difference?

Also, sometimes I need to add Documents when it is already existing. When I use an Array, I would have to check with `include?` before, when I use a Hash, I'd just use `has_key?` again. Same question as above.

What are your thoughts? What is the fastest method of storing large amounts of data when 90% of the time I only need to know whether the ID exists (not the object itself!)

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Hashes are *much* faster for lookups:

```
require 'benchmark'
Document = Struct.new(:id,:a,:b,:c)
documents_a = []
documents_h = {}
1.upto(10_000) do |n|
  d = Document.new(n)
  documents_a << d
  documents_h[d.id] = d
end
searchlist = Array.new(1000){ rand(10_000)+1 }

Benchmark.bm(10) do |x|
  x.report('array'){searchlist.each{|el| documents_a.any?{|d| d.id == el}} }
  x.report('hash'){searchlist.each{|el| documents_h.has_key?(el)} }
end

#                user     system      total        real
#array       2.240000   0.020000   2.260000 (  2.370452)
#hash        0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000695)
```

Comment: That's a surprising and useful result. I expected it, but but didn't expect the difference to be that big.

Comment: Given that the purpose of a hash is to provide constant time lookup, while Array#include? has O(n) worst-case performance, this is not at all surprising.

Comment: Yes, but try upto(10), or even upto(1). The hash is *always* faster, and becomes "fasterer" for larger N.

Comment: Of course this wasn't the question, but a better comparison for membership testing would be sets and hashes.

Comment: @MichaelMior Sets use a hash as storage ,according to [the docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html).

Comment: That may be the case, but that doesn't mean the performance is the same. I did some quick tests and storing a `nil` value in a set and checking membership with `has_key?` outperforms sets somewhat.

Comment: Note that while Hash is fastest for lookups, if you're stuck with arrays Ruby 2.0 introduced [Array#bsearch](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch) which is much faster than `any?`, `include?`, `find/detect`, etc. Added to the above benchmark, yielded ~6x slower than Hash, `any?` being ~ 2000x slower. `x.report('array bsearch'){searchlist.each{|el| documents_a.bsearch {|d| d.id == el}} }`

Comment: @BradNauta bsearch however only works on sorted arrays (which happens to be the case here).

Comment: @steenslag True - thanks for highlighting this gotcha.

Comment: If you know the key will be present, and you are simply accessing the key ex: documents_a[el], arrays are x14 faster. Benchmark: array (  0.000247) VS hash (  0.003607)

Comment: @jBeas yeah, but its not actually `documents_a[el]` but `documents_a[index]` which will return `el`, so you'd have to know the index of the element in the array, which you oftentimes don't know.

Answer (score 7):

When using unique values, you can use the [Ruby Set](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) which has been previously mentioned. Here are benchmark results. It's slightly slower than the hash though.

```
                 user     system      total        real
array        0.460000   0.000000   0.460000 (  0.460666)
hash         0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000219)
set          0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000273)
```

I simply added to @steenslag's code which can be found here https://gist.github.com/rsiddle/a87df54191b6b9dfe7c9.

I used ruby 2.1.1p76 for this test.

Answer (score 5):

Ruby has a set class in its standard library, have you considering keeping an (additional) set of IDs only?

http://stdlib.rubyonrails.org/libdoc/set/rdoc/index.html

To quote the docs: "This is a hybrid of Array’s intuitive inter-operation facilities and Hash’s fast lookup".

Comment: Just a little note: the implementation of Set is based on Hash internally, so performance-wise using Set.include? is the same as Hash.has_key?

Comment: I know, it says so in the docs. I just thought that maybe instead of keeping all documents around, it may make sense to have a set of only IDs and retrieve documents on demand (depending on the cost of document retrieval). Granted I wasn't very explicit about that, but I'm writing from work...

Comment: The doc can now be found here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html

Answer (score 3):

1. Use a Set of Documents. It has most of the properties you want (constant-time lookup and does not allow duplicates),. Smalltalkers would tell you that using a collection that already has the properties you want is most of the battle.
2. Use a Hash of Documents by document id, with ||= for conditional insertion (rather than has_key?).

Hashes are designed for constant-time insertion and lookup. Ruby's Set uses a Hash internally.

Be aware that your Document objects will need to implement #hash and #eql? properly in order for them to behave as you would expect as Hash keys or members of a set, as these are used to define hash equality.