# Performance optimization for implementation of relationship classes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, performance, hash

This one is related to my [previous question on the performance of Arrays and Hashes in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551168/performance-of-arrays-and-hashes-in-ruby).

#### Prerequisites

I know that using Hashes to store lots of Objects leads to significant performance increase because of the *O(1)* lookup.

Now let's assume I had two classes, namely `A` and `B` and they can be related to each other, but only if a third class `C` exists (it's sort of a relationship class). To give a practical example, let's say I have `Document`, `Query` and the relationship class `Judgement` (this is from information retrieval, so basically the judgement tells you whether the document is relevant for a query or not).

[image]

(I hope I got this right)

#### The Problem

In most cases you'd like to find out how many `Judgements` there are for a combination of `Document` and `Query` or if there are any.

In order to find out the latter, I'll iterate over each `Jugdement` ...

```
@judgements.each { |j| return true if j.document == document and j.query == query }
```

Now, this brings us back to a linear search again, which isn't that helpful.

#### How to solve it?

I was thinking about a way to have double Hashes - if there's such a thing - so that I could just look up `Judgements` using the `Document` and `Query` I already have.

Or is there any other way of quickly finding out whether a Judgement exists for a given pair of Document and Query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you need performance, you can always create another data structure to facilitate indexing - in your case you can write a hash where keys would be `[document, query]` pairs, and values arrays of `judgments`. Depending on the architecture of your app, you can either update this index upon every change in your objects, or build indexes from scratch whenever you need to perform a batch of lookups.

Or, perhaps, you should leave it to the database to do your lookups instead, of course, if you have a database at all.

Comment: I don't have a database at all. Didn't know I could just use an Array as a Hash key, that simplifies everything. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This

```
@judgements.each { |j| return true if j.document == document and j.query == query }
```

could be written as

```
@judgements.any? { |j| j.document == document and j.query == query }
```

I agree with Mladen Jablanović in that that's a good chance that you should let your database handle this. In MongoDB it would be something like this

```
db = Mongo::Connection.new.db("mydb")
judgements = db.collection("judgements")
judgement = {:judgement_no=> "2011:73", :document => 4711, :query => 42}
judgements.add(judgement)
judgements.create_index([['document', Mongo::ASCENDING], ['query', Mongo::ASCENDING]])

judgements.find({:document => 4711, :query => 42}).each { |jm| puts jm }
```

Comment: Oh, the upper line works, it's just within a function, so it returns when I found something. I don't have a database layer.

Comment: Ah, of course! I still like `any?` better. I changed the answer.

Comment: Sweet, that's the Ruby way I like :)