# Sort an array of arrays based on the order in another array

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

I have an array of arrays:

```
x = [
  ["ready", 5], ["shipped", 1], ["pending", 1], ["refunded", 1],
  ["delivered", 23], ["scheduled", 1], ["canceled", 51]
]
```

My sorting array is

```
order_array = [
  "ready", "in_progress", "recieved", "shipped", "scheduled", "pick_up",
 "delivered", "canceled", "failed", "refunded", "refund_failed"
]
```

I need to order `x` based on the value of the first element in each subarray. The required sorted array is:

```
[
  ["ready", 5], ["shipped", 1], ["scheduled", 1], ["delivered", 23],
  ["canceled", 51], ["refunded", 1]
]
```

Using `sort_by` doesn't result in the required sorting, it leads to the same array.

```
result = x.sort_by {|u| order_array.index(u)}
# => [
#      ["ready", 5], ["shipped", 1], ["pending", 1], ["refunded", 1],
#      ["delivered", 23], ["scheduled", 1], ["canceled", 51]
# ]
```

Comment: What about `["pending", 1]` – should it be removed because `"pending"` is not an element of `order_array`?

Comment: RE `order_array[2]`:  chant, " 'I' before 'E' except after 'C' or when sounding like 'A' in 'neighbor' or 'weigh' ". (Exceptions exist.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
h = x.to_h
# => {"ready"=>5,
# "shipped"=>1,
# "pending"=>1,
# "refunded"=>1,
# "delivered"=>23,
# "scheduled"=>1,
# "canceled"=>51}

order_array.map{|key| [key, h[key]] if h.key?(key)}.compact
# => [["ready", 5],
# ["shipped", 1],
# ["scheduled", 1],
# ["delivered", 23],
# ["canceled", 51],
# ["refunded", 1]]
```

or

```
h = x.to_h{|k, v| [k, [k, v]]}
#=> {"ready"=>["ready", 5],
# "shipped"=>["shipped", 1],
# "pending"=>["pending", 1],
# "refunded"=>["refunded", 1],
# "delivered"=>["delivered", 23],
# "scheduled"=>["scheduled", 1],
# "canceled"=>["canceled", 51]}

order_array.map{|k| h[k]}.compact
#=> [["ready", 5],
# ["shipped", 1],
# ["scheduled", 1],
# ["delivered", 23],
# ["canceled", 51],
# ["refunded", 1]]
```

or

```
h = x.to_h{|k, v| [k, [k, v]]}
#=> {"ready"=>["ready", 5],
# "shipped"=>["shipped", 1],
# "pending"=>["pending", 1],
# "refunded"=>["refunded", 1],
# "delivered"=>["delivered", 23],
# "scheduled"=>["scheduled", 1],
# "canceled"=>["canceled", 51]}

h.values_at(*order_array).compact
#=> [["ready", 5],
# ["shipped", 1],
# ["scheduled", 1],
# ["delivered", 23],
# ["canceled", 51],
# ["refunded", 1]]
```

Comment: Thanks this works but @SRack solution is much simple.

Comment: @Stefan Right. I implicitly assumed so.

Comment: these is no duplicates.  second solution is also perfect!

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that 2.6 added a block variant for `to_h`. That voids my above comment.

Comment: @Stefan It was according to my request.

Answer (score 4):

You're almost there with this: `index` isn't working as you're comparing the full array, rather than the first element of it. This will work:

```
result = x.sort_by { |u| order_array.index(u[0]) || 100 }
#=> [["ready", 5], ["shipped", 1], ["scheduled", 1], ["delivered", 23], ["canceled", 51], ["refunded", 1], ["pending", 1]]
```

Please note, the `100` is there to default to the back of the sort if the value isn't found in `order_array`.

---

**Edit**

This was initially accepted, despite including `["pending", 1]` suggesting it fit the requirements; however, here's a solution to avoid the unwanted entry, which also handles duplicates should the need arise.

```
order_array.each_with_object([]) { |ordered_by, array| array.push(*x.select { |item| item[0] == ordered_by }) }
#=> [["ready", 5], ["shipped", 1], ["scheduled", 1], ["delivered", 23], ["canceled", 51], ["refunded", 1]]
```

Or, very fast though still allowing for duplicate values under each ordered item:

```
hash = x.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) { |item, h| h[item[0]] << item[1] }
order_array.flat_map { |key| [key, hash[key]] }
```

---

**Benchmark**

Here's a benchmark for this scenario with a larger dataset: https://repl.it/repls/SentimentalAdequateClick. Looks like Sawa's methods lead the way, though my last effort works handily should there be duplicate values in future. Also, my second effort sucks (which surprised me a little) :)

Comment: That does not give what the OP wanted.

Comment: Can see it's including `pending`, which I hadn't noticed was missing above @sawa. Your approach makes more sense if this is essential. Cheers for the comment.

Comment: What is the output that you really wanted?

Comment: I think this fits with the OP's question? The output is added to my answer: it matches the required output, albeit with `["pending", 1]` bumped to the back of the array.

Comment: As you have noted, `["pending", 1]` is added at the end, which the OP has not wanted (according to the question).

Comment: Yep, agree - I've upvoted yours, and mentioned above I prefer your approach due to that. Overlooked the mistake ahead of your comment. This seems to fit Selim's requirements, although yours is definitely the correct one as per the question.

Comment: Edited to include a working solution, which I think is pretty effective @SelimAlawwa.

Comment: Very good! Maybe you want to add the link to the benchmark directly in your answer.

Comment: @SRack, I noticed that the benchmark is on Ruby 2.5 environment, so, the last two methods from Sawa don't return the expected result. Tested on 2.6 are still a lot faster. I edited my post with a further option.

Comment: Thanks @iGian - I'd tested the same on my machine with better results, though hadn't realised Repl.it was on 2.5. Appreciate the clarification.

Answer (score 4):

[assoc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-assoc) seems helpful: "Searches through an array whose elements are also arrays comparing obj with the first element of each contained array using obj.==."

```
order_array.map{|e| x.assoc(e) }.compact
```

Comment: Never seen nor heard of `assoc` before - +1 for bringing it into my life :) Great answer.

Comment: You know that hash is faster :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/5552062/5239030

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest

```
x.keep_if { |e| order_array.include? e[0] }.sort_by { |e| order_array.index(e[0]) }
```

Since some values are not elements of `order_array`, for example `"pending"`.

```
#=> [["ready", 5], ["shipped", 1], ["scheduled", 1], ["delivered", 23], ["canceled", 51], ["refunded", 1]]
```

---

Benchmarked the answers up to now `500.times`:

```
#        user       system     total       real
# sawa   0.006698   0.000132   0.006830 (  0.006996) # on the first method
# ray    0.005543   0.000123   0.005666 (  0.005770)
# igian  0.001923   0.000003   0.001926 (  0.001927)
# srack  0.005270   0.000168   0.005438 (  0.005540) # on the last method
```

---

Just for fun I tried to find a faster method for Ruby 2.5:

```
xx = x.to_h # less than Ruby 2.6
order_array.each.with_object([]) { |k, res| res << [k, xx[k]] if xx.has_key? k }
```

Comment: This was my thought as an edit for mine when I realised my mistake, though it's more complex that @sawa's answer, so didn't think it worthwhile. Still pretty readable though.

Comment: I found it looping 2 times (increasing complexity) and also `index` is quite slow in case of large array.

Comment: @ray, actually the benchmark surprised me. Maybe you can double check? I considered the array to be small in for te OP case.

Comment: @iGian credit where it's due - this does outperform both Ray's and my second answer, even as it scales. I've benchmarked with a larger dataset ([here](https://repl.it/repls/SentimentalAdequateClick)) and it's basically possible to conclude Sawa is king :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code to find output efficiently,

```
order_array.map { |p| x.detect { |y| y[0] == p } }.compact
# => [["ready", 5], ["shipped", 1], ["scheduled", 1], ["delivered", 23], ["canceled", 51], ["refunded", 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've assumed:

- the first element of each element of `x` is not necessarily unique;
- all elements of `x` whose first element is the same and whose first element is a member of `order_array` appear consecutively in the returned (sorted) array in the order in which those elements appear in `x`;
- any elements of `x` whose first element is not a member of `order_array` appears in the returned (sorted) array after all elements whose first element is in `sorted_array`, and all such elements appear in the returned array (at the end) in the order in which they occur in `x`; and
- efficiency is paramount.

```
x = [
  ["ready", 5], ["shipped", 1], ["pending", 1], ["refunded", 1], ["originated", 3],
  ["delivered", 23], ["scheduled", 1], ["ready", 8], ["canceled", 51]
]

order_array = [
  "ready", "in_progress", "received", "shipped", "scheduled", "pick_up",
  "delivered", "canceled", "failed", "refunded", "refund_failed"
]
```

```
order_pos = order_array.each_with_object({}) { |word,h| h[word] = [] }
  #=> {"ready"=>[], "in_progress"=>[], "received"=>[], "shipped"=>[],
  #    "scheduled"=>[], "pick_up"=>[], "delivered"=>[], "canceled"=>[],
  #    "failed"=>[], "refunded"=>[], "refund_failed"=>[]} 
back = x.each_with_index.with_object([]) { |((word,v),i),back|
  order_pos.key?(word) ? (order_pos[word] << i) : back << [word,v] }
  #=> [["pending", 1], ["originated", 3]] 
order_pos.flat_map { |word,offsets| offsets.map { |i| x[i] } }.concat(back)
  #=> [["ready", 5], ["ready", 8], ["shipped", 1], ["scheduled", 1],
  #    ["delivered", 23], ["canceled", 51], ["refunded", 1], ["pending", 1],
  #    ["originated", 3]]
```

Note:

```
order_pos
  #=> {"ready"=>[0, 7], "in_progress"=>[], "received"=>[], "shipped"=>[1],
  #    "scheduled"=>[6], "pick_up"==>[], "delivered"=>[5], "canceled"=>[8],
  #    "failed"=>[], "refunded"=>[3], "refund_failed"=>[]}
```

It is necessary to initialise `order_pos` in order for its keys to be ordered by `order_arr`. This is an example of the worth of a controversial change made in Ruby 1.9 which guaranteed that hash keys will remain in key-insertion order.